# place view depending on superview background image using autolayout

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

[image]
 I have a blue background image and have some logo in it which is shown by 
 black rectangle.

I want to design one login screen for my application.

login screen will have:

username
usernameTextField

Password
PasswordTextField

LoginButton

i want to place all this under that logo

i was trying it by putting all the labels,textfields and buttons in one view and apply constraints to that view.

how can i do it using autolayout so it can run on all devices

This will be the login screen

[image]

Comment: Why don't you have a separate logo and use the image view to show the black logo. The way you are trying to do is not possible, and for a simple login screen you don't have to do unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can center your view containing username and password , so they look centered and adjust your background imageview to have your logo above the centered view , something like this

[image: constraints for above methord]

or you can alter the constraint for your content view's(username & password) center so that the content view starts below the logo .

[image: Something like this]

You can even choose to have diffrent horizontal and vertical spacing depending on how you want the view to look.  Autolayouts can be applied with diffrent combination depending on how you want it to look.